# Laravel multiple routes connect to one controller using same view

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create dynamic routes that connect to one controller. The controller will then return the same view with dynamic data based on different routes.

Here are my routes; it generates three routes cat/1, cat/2, cat/3.

```
Route::get('cat/{id}', 'PagesController@getCat')->where('id', '(1|2|3)');
```

**Controller**

```
public function getCat($id) 
{
    $post = Post::find($id);

    return view('Pages.cat')->withPost($post);
}
```

It gets the `$id` and its related post data and returns them to the view.

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <th>Part</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Style</th>
        <th>Series</th>
        <th>Length</th>
        <th>Size</th>
        <th>Category</th>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $post->part }}</td>
            <td>{{ $post->description }}</td>
            <td>{{ $post->style }}</td>
            <th>{{ $post->series }}</th>
            <td>{{ $post->length }}</td>
            <td>{{ $post->size }}</td>
            <td>{{ $post->category }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

It works. But I am new to Laravel, and I am not sure if that the right way to do it. So I would like to know the best practice for this.

Comment: yeah, this is the common way to handle this kind of situation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add id with where condition in routes please change it to

```
Route::get('cat/{id}', 'PagesController@getCat');
```

if you want to pass optional id then

```
Route::get('cat/{id?}', 'PagesController@getCat');
```

Comment: so if I don't pass the $id with the where condition, I assume I should pass in the $id dynamically with the a tag? Some thing like this `<a href="{{ url('cat/' . $post->id)}}">view</a>
`

Comment: Yes, Liang this is the way, we can get specific post by id

Answer (score 0):

your routes and controller code are good.
I think its the best way to dynamic routes